# How do i properly use pinia store on Vue3 + Pinia + Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I struggle on using Pinia store with typescript and using store inside basic app.vue Vuejs3 option api.

I have this app.js file

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import {createPinia} from "pinia";

import App from './App';
const pinia = createPinia()

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(pinia);

app.mount('#app');
```

This app.vue

```
<script>
import {useAuthStore} from "@app/store/auth.store";
import {useCountryStore} from "@app/store/country.store";

export default {
  components: {SidebarMenu},
  setup() {
    return {
      authStore: useAuthStore(),
      countryStore: useCountryStore(),
    }
  },
  computed: {
    loggedIn: function () {
      return this.authStore.status.loggedIn;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This authStore.js :

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia";

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", {
    state: () => (
        user ? {status: {loggedIn: true}, user}  : {status: {loggedIn: false}, user: null}
    ),
});
```

And this CountryStore.ts

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { Country } from "@app/interfaces/country";

export type CountryState = {
    countries: Country[],
    errors: any[],
}

export const useCountryStore = defineStore("country", {
    state: () => ({
        countries: [],
        errors: []
    } as CountryState)
})
```

In my case, no matter what i do i get this error because of countryStore but not AuthStore:

```
getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
```

But for whatever reason. If i turn my countryStore.ts into .js (and removing type hinting of course), it work!

I search a lot about why it does that, what i am missing or what do i do wrong.
Of course i want to keep typescript in the end but i don't know how to make it work.

Thanks to anyone who can help me. Love you all.

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce it? I'd expect that your case differs in some way. I see nothing that could cause the behaviour. In order to cause this error a store needs to be used outside component setup function, but in your case it's not so. The way .js vs .ts works is specific to your setup, which is unknown

Comment: @EstusFlask so basically, your telling me everything seems good to you but still do not work haha. 
I really don't know what to provide to improve my question. 
I literally commented all the code except what i copy pasted in the question to reduce "border effect". 
Im using webpack encore from symfony to build assets. Maybe i can its config ?
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Does app.js need to be turn into app.ts ? I literally dont find a proper way to troubleshoot my issue with a "logic approach"

Comment: Here is my tsconfig.json
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./assets",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}`

Comment: I didn't notice app.js, yes, it should be app.ts, it's incorrect to use .js TS project without respective .d.ts type. It really depends on a specific setup how it works, not just on TS config alone. It's Webpack in your case that makes modules work together, so it's specific to Webpack config that Encore generates.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for all your help. Even if it was not a direct answer, at least it helped me to "think" about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i figured it out myself by trying multiple things. Nothing is wrong with Pinia.
My major issue was, i started the project without typescript and started to implement it after on "some file"

If you want to enable typescript, switch **all** your .js file in .ts
This is not needed for .vue
Then here is a list of various i've done to make everything work :

Use this tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./assets", //this is your working folder, usually ./ only, since i'm using webpack encore + symfony i adapted it
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": { // very important to make your import @app work
      "@app/*": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "assets/**/*.ts",
    "assets/**/*.tsx",
    "assets/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Add  shims-vue.d.ts inside your main folder (/assets for me), i still dont know why this is needed but it saved me

```
declare module '*.vue' {
    import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
    const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
    export default component
}
```

Dont forget this when creating components

```
<script lang="ts">
```

Dont forget to turn your main.js or app.js into .ts
And adapt webpack.config.js encore

```
.addEntry('app', './assets/app.ts')
.addAliases({
     '@app': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/') //usefull for @app/ in import, you can also only use @, adapt it on your desire
})
```

After this you will get a lot of compiled error related to things to adapat in your code.

One trick is .vue file not gonna be imported and throw "module not found"

For example, i had to switch from :

```
import App from './App';
```

To :

```
import App from './App.vue';
```

If everyone have better practice, feel free to share and i will adapt my answer

Comment: Additionally, in .vue it should be `<script lang="ts">`

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the defineStore a name as a first argument then the options object as the second argument. Just as you did on your authStore.

from:

```
export const useCountryStore = defineStore( {
    id: "country",
    state: () => ({
        countries: [],
        errors: []
    } as CountryState)
})
```

to:

```
export const useCountryStore = defineStore("country", {
    id: "country",
    state: () => ({
        countries: [],
        errors: []
    } as CountryState)
})
```

Comment: I was just a bad copy paste on stackoverflow, it was already like your answer on my original code. I changed many things to try to make it work. Sorry it does not change anything. 
Anyway, thanks for trying to help.